# Работа с медиа (изображениями) в Tkinter Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

нигде нормальной инфы не нашёл. Прошу знатоков рассказать мне как использовать изображения в каком либо окне на языке Python с помощью модуля Tkinter.

Допустим есть такое окно:

```py
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
root.title('Hi-Lo')
root.geometry('700x425')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


but = Button(root, text="Click me!")
but.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='goldenrod', command=window)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Пусть чуть ниже кнопки будет изображение. Расскажите о функция для этого и можно управлять их размеры и использовать методы pack/place?

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления картинки используйте PIL

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image 
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Hi-Lo')
root.geometry('700x425')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


but = Button(root, text="Click me!")
but.config(width=25, height=2, fg='black', bg='goldenrod', command='window')
but.pack()

path = r"img.png"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: а зачем перед "img.png" буква r?

Comment: Замените: `Image.open((path))` на `Image.open(path)`

Comment: Ошибка, не видит PIL

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов Возможно не установлен этот модуль. Установите его или попробуйте без него.
Вместо img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path)) используйте img = PhotoImage(file=path).
r для того, чтобы не возникло проблем с escape символами в строке.

Comment: pip install PIL вводил и вот:

Comment: Collecting PIL
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PIL
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов pip install pillow